# que significa esto después de la llave de cierre de un método: </variableX></variableX></variableX>

Tags: java

Estoy viendo un tutorial para trabajar con JCalendar y venía todo perfecto hasta que me encontré con el siguiente método:

```
public static List<calendar> fechasEspeciales() {
 List<calendar> fechas = new ArrayList<calendar>();

 Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2015, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 10);
 fechas.add(calendar);
 calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2015, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 10);
 fechas.add(calendar);
 calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2015, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 18);
 fechas.add(calendar);

 return fechas;
}
 </calendar></calendar></calendar>
```

El método devuelve un List, donde 'calendar' es un objeto JCalendar que tengo declarado como atributo en la misma clase donde se encuentra este método. No entiendo esto, ya que lo poco que sé es que dentro del diamante se escribe el TIPO de dato, que para mi debería ser Calendar(mayúscula). Y lo otro que no entiendo es eso que hay al final: .

Comment: Si pudieras poner el enlace del tutorial sería de gran ayuda. En principio, lo que comentas tiene sentido: entre los paréntesis angulares (¿?) debe aparecer el nombre de una clase que, normalmente, se escriben en mayúscula aunque no tienen por qué

Comment: Si el tutorial es este: http://datojava.blogspot.com/2015/11/jcalendarJavaSwingEjemploTutorial.html, creo que puedes poner `List<Calendar>` en lugar de `List<calendar>` y eliminar la línea con `</calendar></calendar></calendar>`

Comment: Si, ese mismo, buen tutorial. Hice eso y funciona, pasa que tenia otro problema  que me daba error de compilación  y era que había importado java.awt.List en vez de java.util.List, entonces no funcionaba de ninguna de las dos formas

Comment: Efectivamente, como te comentaron el tutorial que estabas viendo tenía errores tipográficos.